# Django - Chaining annotated querysets

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to chain two querysets that have different annotated values based on some filters (which are simplified in the following snippet)

```
queryset = Location.objects.all()
queryset_1 = queryset.filter(dummy=True).annotate(weight=Value(1, IntegerField()))
queryset_2 = queryset.filter(dummy=False).annotate(weight=Value(0, IntegerField()))
queryset = queryset_1 | queryset_2
```

However, if I iterate the queryset and try to print the weight, if will be 1 for the whole queryset

```
for p in queryset:
    print(p, p.weight)

5587798: <True> 1
5587810: <True> 1
5587811: <True> 1
5587819: <False> 1
5587823: <False> 1
5587824: <True> 1
```

Is it possible to keep the annotated value, so the objects that are dummy=False have an annotated value of 0, and the ones that have it set to true have an annotated value of 1?

Comment: What if you use `queryset = queryset_1.union(queryset_2)`?

Comment: I get the following error, Arguments: ('Calling QuerySet.filter() after union() is not supported.',).

I guess this is due to the fact that I am doing further filters after the union

Comment: I think it might be better to do that filtering in the first `queryset`, then normally you can make a union with the filtered querysets afterwards.